# Executar arquivo com scripts diretamente no PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Tenho um `arquivo.sql`, do qual tem milhares de linhas de scripts, contendo, criações, alterações, etc.

Preciso executar esse arquivo diretamente no PLSQL em `SQL Window`, e **não** pode ser via `Command Window`.

---

Via `Command Window`, dessa forma funciona:

```
@c:\arquivo.sql
```

---

Via `SQL Window`, tentei das seguintes formas, mas sem sucesso:

**1. Executando diretamente**

```
@c:\arquivo.sql
```

**Erro:**

> ORA-00900: instrução SQL inválida

**2. Executando diretamente**

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '@c:\arquivo.sql'
```

**Erro:**

> ORA-00900: instrução SQL inválida

**3. Criando uma procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_run_script IS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '@c:\arquivo.sql';
END p_run_script;
/
BEGIN
    p_run_script;
END;
/
```

**Erro:**

> ORA-00900: instrução SQL inválida ORA-06512: em
>   "P_RUN_SCRIPT", line 3 ORA-06512: em line 2

**Observação:** Não posso enviar esse arquivo para o servidor, nem criar um diretorio no oracle, ou utilizar `dbms_pipe`.

Não precisa ser uma resposta com o script e completa, mas se falar somente o que pesquisar já é de grande ajudar.

Comment: Está executando remotamente? Está usando o SQL Plus?

Comment: Não, via plsql mesmo.. Vlw @linq

Comment: Só é possível fazer isso via sql plus. Aconcelho você a criar uma procedure com o seu script.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde, consegui fazer assim:

**1** - Abrindo a opção command window

**2** - `SQL> @"c:\arquivo.sql"`

Observe que o "@" está fora das aspas e não tem ";".

Comment: Obrigado Odisley peloa resposta, mas não pode ser vice Command Windows :/